# Connect from Linux command line to FTP server with proxy

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I want to connect to an FTP server from the Linux command line. The server is configured behind a proxy.

If I call:

```
echo $ftp_proxy
```

I get a result like this:

```
abc.def.ghi.jkl:8080
```

If I call:

```
ftp -pn $ftp_proxy
```

I get a unknown host error.

How can I connect to the FTP server using the Linux command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an address:port and ftp, you cannot use the colon.  ftp is expecting two parameters  as `ftp -pn host port`.

Use a space instead of the colon.

```
example="abc.def.ghi 8080"
ftp -pn $example
```